# How to add frame number to footline

Tags: beamer, header-footer, numbering

```
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\setbeamercovered{invisible}
\addtobeamertemplate{block begin}{\setlength\abovedisplayskip{0pt}}
```

In footline I have authors and title. I would like to add frame number on the right. When I use  `\setbeamertemplate{footline}[frame number]` then my footline disappear and there is only frame number on the right. What should I do?

Example:

```
\documentclass[english]{beamer}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\renewcommand{\sfdefault}{lmss}
\renewcommand{\ttdefault}{lmtt}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\makeatletter
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Textclass specific LaTeX commands.
% this default might be overridden by plain title style
\newcommand\makebeamertitle{\frame{\maketitle}}%
% (ERT) argument for the TOC
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \let\origtableofcontents=\tableofcontents
  \def\tableofcontents{\@ifnextchar[{\origtableofcontents}{\gobbletableofcontents}}
  \def\gobbletableofcontents#1{\origtableofcontents}
}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% User specified LaTeX commands.
\usetheme{Warsaw}
% or ...

\setbeamercovered{transparent}
% or whatever (possibly just delete it)

\makeatother

\usepackage{babel}
\begin{document}
\title{Title}
\author{Authors}
\makebeamertitle
\begin{frame}{Frame 1}

...
\end{frame}
%
\begin{frame}{Frame 2}

...
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Screen:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default under the `Warsaw` outer theme is to not print any frame/page numbers. You'll have to manually set the `page number in head/foot` template using something like

```
\setbeamertemplate{page number in head/foot}[totalframenumber]
```

This prints an `X/Y` style frame number (of a total number of frames) in the bottom right footer.

[image]

From the [`beamer`](//ctan.org/pkg/beamer) [documentation](//texdoc.net/pkg/beamer):

> The following template options are predefined:
>
> • `[default]` The default option is empty.
> • `[framenumber]` This option inserts the current frame number.
> • `[totalframenumber]` In addition to the current frame number, this option also shows the total number of frames.
> • `[appendixframenumber]` This options replicates the behaviour of the `appendixnumberbeamer` package. In the main part before the `\appendix` command the current frame number and the total number of frames in the main part is displayed. In the appendix only the frame number within the appendix and the total number of frames in the appendix are shown.
> • `[pagenumber]` Shows the current page number.
> • `[totalpagenumber]` In addition to the current page number also the total page number is displayed.

One could also define your own `page number in head/foot` template. For example, this is how it is defined for `totalframenumber` (in [`beamerbaseauxtemplates.sty`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/base/beamerbaseauxtemplates.sty)):

```
\defbeamertemplate{page number in head/foot}{totalframenumber}
  {\insertframenumber\,/\,\inserttotalframenumber}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted, thanks :)